# Entity Framework - Foreign Key name

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm having some problems in creating a Foreign Key with a code first approach.

This is my `UserTable`

```cs
public class UserTable
{
    //USERNAME
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //NAVIGATION PROPERTY
    public virtual ICollection<AuctionTable> Auctions { get; set; }

}
```

And this is my `AuctionTable`

```cs
public class AuctionTable
{
        //AUCTION ID
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int AuctionId { get; set; }

        //NAVIGATION PROPERTY
        public string Seller { get; set; }
        public virtual UserTable Users{ get; set; }
}
```

Seller should my FK but the program seems to recognize it only if I rename it as "`Username`" (the primary key of the other table).

I've tried using the foreign key tag `[ForeignKey("UserTable")]` over `Seller`, but it didn't work.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

make this your AuctionTable:

```
public class AuctionTable
{
    //AUCTION ID
    [Key]
    public int AuctionId { get; set; }

    //NAVIGATION PROPERTY
    public string Seller { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Seller")]
    public virtual UserTable Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code First has a set or rules it applies to try and locate a foreign key property when it discovers a relationship. The rules are based *on the name of the property*. The foreign key property will be discovered by convention if it is named `[Target Type Key Name]`, `[Target Type Name] + [Target Type Key Name]`, or `[Navigation Property Name] + [Target Type Key Name].` The `Seller` property you added not matched with any of these three rules. Adding `ForeignKey` attribute to the `Seller` FK property, along with information telling it which navigation property represents the relationship it is a foreign key for, will fix the problem:

```
public class AuctionTable
{
    [Key]
    public int AuctionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string Seller { get; set; }

    public virtual UserTable User { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can apply the `ForeignKey` annotation to the navigation property ( as @Andy shows in his answer) and tell it which property is the foreign key for the relationship.